# A weekly review in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, gtd

I'd like to generate an agenda view from org-mode which includes completed TODO items from the previous week. The following snippet seems like the prefered way to do it from reading the docs. However there are no items displayed in the agenda, only dates...

```
    (setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
      '(("W" "Completed and/or deferred tasks from previous week"
         ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7)
              (org-agenda-start-day "-7d")
              (org-agenda-entry-types '(:timestamp :sexp))))))))
```

For example, the built in command `C-a-a` produces a list like this in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer

```
Week-agenda (W27):
Monday      1 July 2013 W27
  gtd:        Scheduled:  DONE something important
Tuesday     2 July 2013
Wednesday   3 July 2013
Thursday    4 July 2013
Friday      5 July 2013
Saturday    6 July 2013
Sunday      7 July 2013
```

...but the custom command `C-a-W` as defined above produces this (despite various scheduled tasks during the period)

```
Week-agenda (W26):
Monday     24 June 2013 W26
Tuesday    25 June 2013
Wednesday  26 June 2013
Thursday   27 June 2013
Friday     28 June 2013
Saturday   29 June 2013
Sunday     30 June 2013
```

Alternatively is there another way to generate a list of DONE items from the previous week?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some trawling through `C-h-v` output, it looks like this is possible using log display in the agenda. (i.e. `C-a-a` then pressing `l` in the `*Org-Agenda*` buffer)

A custom command to produce something close enough to the required output looks like this...

```
   (setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
      ("W" "Completed and/or deferred tasks from previous week"
       ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7)
            (org-agenda-start-day "-7d")
            (org-agenda-entry-types '(:timestamp))
            (org-agenda-show-log t))))))
```

It may be possible to further limit display by tags...

Answer (score -1):

By definition, the agenda only displays things to do, not completed (ie, DONE) things.

Hence, you must use another type of command:

```
(todo "DONE"
      (...))
```

Comment: In that case, what can be added to this (i.e. the '...' above) to limit the DONE items to the previous week?

Comment: The agenda can display completed tasks when it is in log-mode (e.g. press `l` in the agenda buffer or `C-a-a` then `l` from an org file)